# Unable to set Hostname for new Jenkins node configuration

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to configure Jenkins permanent node for remote Linux server.

My Jenkins master is on Windows.

Unfortunately I do not get the option to enter the hosts details and it populates by login ID in place of Hosts. (Please see snapshot)

[image]

I'm using ssh keys in the credentials for user root.

I guess I have all the required plugins.

I'm on the latest version of Jernkins.

Can you please suggest how can i fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my username was for someone reason set in the hostname under credentials for Jenkins.

Deleting the same from the Jenkins credentials resolved the hostname issue for the slave node and now I m able to enter the correct IP.